# Type hinting json object in Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony-2.3

In my Symfony 2.3 project, I have a curl function that receives JSON data from an API and passes this data as a parameter to another function. Currently, the function that accepts the JSON object looks like this:

```
public function updateCountries($data)
{
    foreach (json_decode($data, true) as $key => $value) {
        (do something)
    }
}
```

I'd like to add a type hint to the $data parameter to indicate that this is a JSON object, but a "JSON" type doesn't seem to exist. Is there a type hint that would work?

Comment: But your $data is a string, not a php object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP doesn't support JSON as a type. $data would come in as a string and be converted to a array when you call json_decode() on it. You can make a method that takes a  json string as a argument and returns a array. Then type hit updateCountries with Array.